# Overcoming SAME ORIGIN policy to allow for iframing a single page

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, nginx

Our servers are setup to use `SAMEORIGIN` on our entire site, and I'm wanting to let a single page be iframeable on the site.

We're using PHP and setting `header('X-Frame-Options: AnythingElse')` just adds it to the options, which means I still can't iframe that single page.

In short, we want to allow people to iframe a single URL and our sysadmin doesn't care for setting the same origin policy in code as opposed to on the server level.

I've looked into a lot of ways around this, but none of them will work with minimal work for the users.

It all involves some crazy Javascript when I'd prefer to just allow them to do a simple `<iframe>` tag.

What are my options for this?

Comment: you have to change it in code or on the server level, pick one if you want to use an iframe. we recently removed the header at work for the same reason, and the fact that X-Frame-Options is deprecated anyway.,,